# C++ - Using a variable as the variable name in getline

Tags: c++, variables, getline

I'm looping through a series of Q&A's in order to dodge repeated code and easier manage the questions being asked.

Not much more I can say until you see an example:

```
string nameOfUser, nameOfCourse; // define

string varNames [] = { nameOfUser, nameOfCourse };
string varDesc [] = { "Please enter your name:", "Please enter the course name:" };

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  cout << varDesc[i] << endl;
  getline( cin, varNames[i] );
  cout << endl;
}
```

The above code ultimately produces nothing from the user's input.

I believe the issue lies in trying to loop the the array `varNames` in `getline`. It appears as if it thinks `varNames[i]` is a variable name itself - I assumed early on that it would print the corresponding value when looped, but this is obviously not the case.

Simply put, is it possible to simply use the the value of the variable as the name of the variable, or is this an impossibility in terms of `getline`?

I'm not exactly thinking of 'variable variable names' here (I understand that it's an impossibility in C++), but the way I see it it should be able to use the values in the `varNames` array when looping.

Comment: What is `nameOfUser`?  You don't show it, and your code won't compile without it.

Comment: @John Zwinck It's defined earlier in the program, I'll go ahead and include it in the example just to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++, variable names only exist in your source code; they disappear once the program is run. So it's impossible to use the stored name of a variable to access the actual variable in C++.

However, you can put pointers into an array like this to gain similar behavior:

```
string nameOfUser, nameOfCourse;

string * p[2] = {&nameOfUser, &nameOfCourse};

for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {

    cout << varDesc[i] << endl;
    getline(cin, *(p[i]));
    cout << endl;

}
```

Here, `p` references the variables by their memory address, rather than their name.

Answer (score 2):

This is an ideal use case for the C++ map data structure, along the lines of:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> myMap;
```

The first string will be the "variable name" and the second its value input by the user.

See the following program for a way to do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main (void)
{
    std::map<std::string,std::string> vars;
    std::string entry, varNames[] = {"name of user", "name of course" };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(varNames) / sizeof(varNames[0]); i++) {
        std::cout << "Enter " << varNames[i] << ": ";
        std::getline( std::cin, entry );
        vars[varNames[i]] = entry;
    }

    std::cout << "Name  : " << vars[varNames[0]] << '\n';
    std::cout << "Course: " << vars[varNames[1]] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```